# Stub file not found for "behave"PylancereportMissingTypeStubs

Tags: python-behave, pylance

When I'm creating features folder here:

```
project/test/features/steps
```

I got this error when I'm doing the import

```
from behave import * 

Stub file not found for "behave" PylancereportMissingTypeStubs
```

But when I'm creating the folder at the root of the project there is no error.

Can someone explain ?

I'm trying to find a param in the config file or something that I can change :)